# Looking for SQL Server 2014 SP1 Build 12.0.4213.0

Tags: sql-server, sql

I'm trying to install a new SQL Server 2014 instance, on a new machine, with this version:

SQL Server 2014 SP1 Build 12.0.4213.0

I have it installed on one of my machines, but I have no clue how to get to this exact build.

I searched for updates / patches but I didn't find any download link.

I can install 12.0.4100.0, but I don't know how to get to the specific version from there.

Comment: Your google-fu was mislead by a missing zero. Search instead for [12.00.4213](http://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As jscott mentions in the comments, your version number is a bit off. Using [the site he links to](http://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/) you can see that once you are at `12.00.4100`, if you install [MS15-058: Description of the nonsecurity update for SQL Server 2014 Service Pack 1 GDR: July 14, 2015](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3070446/ms15-058-description-of-the-nonsecurity-update-for-sql-server-2014-service-pack-1-gdr-july-14,-2015) you will be at `12.00.4213`